# Ionic Push Notification Using GCM

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm work in Ionic Push Notification App and take the reference of https://www.sitepoint.com/push-notifications-in-ionic-apps-with-google-cloud-messaging/ but in this I can't get Android Device token.

When I request from the server (`https://localhost:3000/register`) I'm getting 401/Undefined in server console.

Anyone help me out for this.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: hi Shashanth , Code Link : http://pastebin.com/ExBKm48n